# Как перейти с одного Activity в другое Activity при долгом нажатии на текст (НЕ КНОПКА)?

Tags: android, kotlin

Мне нужно чтобы ТОЛЬКО при долгом нажатии на текст "Hello World!" (где-то 3-5 сек.) одно Activity переходило в другое.

Comment: на какой текст? может что-то покажете? это виджет или что?

Comment: Нет, это не виджет. К примеру, val txtView : TextView = findViewById(R.id.helloworld). мне нужно чтобы переменная txtView выполняла метод, который отвечает за долгое нажатие. Но мне нужно чтобы только после 3-5 секунд нажатия на текст текущее Activity переходило в другое Activity

Comment: эм... хорошо давайте назовем ваш textView не виджетом) но сути это не меняет

Answer (score 1):

Что то типа такого:

```
textView.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {blah-blah})
```

Answer (score 0):

По факту у вас есть возможность использовать стандартный метод:

```
view.setOnLongClickListener{
     Toast.makeText(this, "Long click detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
     true
}
```

но его продолжительность где-то `500ms` ([первоисточник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930895/how-long-is-the-event-onlongpress-in-the-android) + [доки](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#getLongPressTimeout())). Если же вам нужно принципиально ждать 3-5 секунды, то вам данный способ не подойдет.  Можно использовать например такую конструкцию:

```
fun View.setOnVeryLongClickListener(listener: () -> Unit) {
    setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {

        private val longClickDuration = 2000L
        private val handler = Handler()

        override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            if (event?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                handler.postDelayed({ listener.invoke() }, longClickDuration)
            } else if (event?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
            }
            return true
        }
    })
}
```

и вызывать метод:

```
view.setOnVeryLongClickListener {
    // Do something here
}
```

[вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958418/change-long-click-delay) можно посмотреть и другие варианты решения.